# HDMI issues using Samsung AU55RU8000WXXY as monitor

Tags: hdmi, output, tv

I have been happily using my Samsung tv as a monitor for my Ubuntu based mythtv system, but over the last couple of weeks it has become unreliable. Sometimes the Tv connects to the pc, but more often than not the Tv says "no signal". 
I have tried various combinations of turning the Tv on 1st etc, and occasionally the screen displays almost to the login screen and then "no signal" appears. Other times it starts with "no signal" and then suddenly it will start working.
My pc hardware is a Zotac pc with an on-board Intel video card.
It used to work well but with no hardware changes this has happened. I suspect that the Ubuntu os is turning of the HDMI output for some reason.
Any suggestions about how to force it to enable the port or otherwise fault find would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed now. The problem was the hdmi port on the TV. I swapped the cable to a different port and all has been fine since. I contacted Samsung support and they wasted my time and failed to fix the problem. I have a fairly new TV now that has a faulty hdmi port.
Thumbs down to Samsung.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching HDMI cables. Try running a known good system (dvd player, laptop) with the TV to troubleshoot the HDMI cable and TV Ports.

Comment: These were part of my initial trouble shooting procedures. I should add that I've now noticed that after a while it realizes that it has something connected to the HDMI port and then would flawlessly. The trouble is that I don't want to wait for 10 or 15 minutes for it to start. With a device like a DVD player on the same port it works instantly. I'm fairly sure that the issue is the pc not initially detecting the connection.

Comment: I would try updating the graphics driver. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072420

        sudo apt-get install mesa-utils 
        
I would try running this command first, to install mesa-utils and testing before updating any drivers.